# No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib' <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, nlp

[This is my function save_load_model which is throwing the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUAjx.png)

Comment: just type import joblib

Comment: Thanks tanveer but thats not working, can you check whether i am dumping and loading correctly?

Comment: never ever import in scope of the function.. import outside of the function

Comment: if i import just before the function ..it says variable 'joblib' referenced before assignment